# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, file, download, dropbox-api

I have got this code's lines:

```
import dropbox

#some lines for initialize API's

download = self.client.get_file_and_metadata(selected_path)
current_working = os.getcwd()
out = open(current_working+self.filename,'w')
out.write(download.read())
out.close()
```

where 'selected_path' is the path where there is the file I want to download and 'current_working' is the path where I want to save the file.
When I run the script, I retrieve this error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

The file that I want to download is a GPG crypted file, but I don't think that is this the matter.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: "When I run the script, I retrieve this error". **No**. When you run the script you get a nice *complete* traceback, not just the last line. Why do you think the interpreter gives you the rest of the information if not for helping to understand what's going on? And then why didn't you copy the **full** traceback in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `get_file_and_metadata` returns **tuple**: file and metadata.

from here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python

> In addition to the file, the method also returns the file's metadata
>   at its current revision. Every time a change is made to the file, the
>   rev field of the file's metadata changes as well. By saving the
>   revision when you download the file, you'll be able to tell if that
>   file has been updated by another computer or device and choose to
>   download the newer revision of that file.

change your call to `self.client.get_file_and_metadata` like this:

```
download, metadata = self.client.get_file_and_metadata(selected_path)
```

or just use `get_file` if you dont need the metadata:

```
download = self.client.get_file(selected_path)
```

Comment: Or just do `download = self.client.get_file(selected_path)` if you don't need the metadata.